# Error in Connecting WSO2 ESB and WSO2 DAS

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, event-receiver, wso2-esb

I have tried to connect DAS with the wso2 ESB  (Both are latest versions) according to the following article. [Reference document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Monitoring+WSO2+ESB+with+WSO2+Analytics) . I followed all the steps according the document. But now I'm getting error like,

```
       ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7612 org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointSecurityException: Error while trying to connect to ssl://localhost:7612
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:91)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not connect to localhost on port 7612
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createClient(TSSLTransportFactory.java:237)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getClientSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:169)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.thrift.ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(ThriftSecureClientPoolFactory.java:56)
        ... 9 more
```

As per the log, it seems there is no event receiver for ESB in the DAS.
But nothing is mentioned in the document.
Is there any .car file for event receiver and etc in the DAS side or 
can any one tell me what are the required configuration should be done on DAS side.

Comment: This exception is thrown when ESB is trying to connect to the defined ssl connection. Therefore you have to start the Analytics/DAS node before you start the ESB server.

Comment: I already did like that. DAS first, then ESB. This seems not having event receiver in the DAS side

Comment: Did you use the analytics pack mentioned in http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/? Also you can log in to Analytics Server -> Event -> Flow and check whether event receivers and publisher deployed successfully

Comment: yes I used the analytics car file to ESB. Ok i'll check more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also getting the same error.

Fix is simple. For me Issue was with event syn configuration of ESB.
Replace right IP in localhost and right port in port number in both ssl:// and tcp:// configuration.

I fixed the issue by following steps from below video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bgeUIVKwZE